# angularjs with pickadate.js how?

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbi in angularjs

how do I get [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm) to work in angularjs

I can get pickadate.js to work but how do i get pickadate.js to work with angularjs to use it in §scope

Answer (score 1):

If you are not forced to use pickadate.js: What about using [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (a modified Twitter Bootstrap Library to be compatible with AngularJS) and use the datepicker that is included in there?

The problem is, that any JavaScript framework (in your case the pickadate.js) needs to be modified to be compatible with AngularJS. Same for Twitter Bootstrap, this does not work out of the box with AngularJS - so, in this case the Angular team itself rewrote Bootstrap to be compatible.

Comment: Okay so it's probably why I can not get it to work
I've got Twitter Boostrap datepicker to work but I would like to use pickadate.js because I feel it is the Best for mobile phones

Comment: AngularUI doesn't have a time component from what I can see, plus the issues with being responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished writing [pickadate.js as an AngularJS directive](http://www.codinginsight.com/angularjs-and-pickadate/). Check it out and you can download the sample code too!
Cheers!

If you want the directive itself, here is the code for it:

```
// pick-a-date (attribute)
angular.module('ng').directive('pickADate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A", 
        scope: {
            pickADate: '=',
            minDate: '=',
            maxDate: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickadate({
                onSet: function (e) {
                    if (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) // we are coming from $watch or link setup
                        return;
                    var select = element.pickadate('picker').get('select'); // selected date
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (e.hasOwnProperty('clear') || !select) {
                            scope.pickADate = null;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!scope.pickADate)
                            scope.pickADate = new Date(0);
                        scope.pickADate.setYear(select.obj.getYear() + 1900); // hello Y2K...
                        // It took me half a day to figure out that javascript Date object's getYear
                        // function returns the years since 1900. Ironically setYear() accepts the actual year A.D.
                        // So as I got the $#%^ 114 and set it, guess what, I was transported to ancient Rome 114 A.D.
                        // That's it I'm done being a programmer, I'd rather go serve Emperor Trajan as a sex slave.
                        scope.pickADate.setMonth(select.obj.getMonth());
                        scope.pickADate.setDate(select.obj.getDate());
                    });
                },
                onClose: function () {
                    element.blur();
                }
            });
            function updateValue(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    scope.pickADate = (newValue instanceof Date) ? newValue : new Date(newValue);
                    // needs to be in milliseconds
                    element.pickadate('picker').set('select', scope.pickADate.getTime());
                } else {
                    element.pickadate('picker').clear();
                    scope.pickADate = null;
                }
            }
            updateValue(scope.pickADate);
            element.pickadate('picker').set('min', scope.minDate ? scope.minDate : false);
            element.pickadate('picker').set('max', scope.maxDate ? scope.maxDate : false);
            scope.$watch('pickADate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue == oldValue)
                    return;
                updateValue(newValue);
            }, true);
            scope.$watch('minDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                element.pickadate('picker').set('min', newValue ? newValue : false);
            }, true);
            scope.$watch('maxDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                element.pickadate('picker').set('max', newValue ? newValue : false);
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker is pickadate forked to work with Angular.

Add `<script src="angular-datepicker.js"> </script>`

Use it like:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" pick-a-date="date" pick-a-date-options="dpoptions" placeholder="Select date" />
```

And in your controller

> ```
>    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angular-datepicker']);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>     $scope.dpoptions = {
>         format: 'ddd, dd-mm-yyyy' // ..etc
>     }
> ```